# Active Record Autosave In Reverse Direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, autosave

Using [autosave: true](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) on a `has_one` or `has_many` association means that when the parent record is saved, its association(s) are saved as well.

But what if I need the parent to be saved whenever (any of) its association(s) are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use autosave:true on a [belongs_to relationship](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) to automatically save the parent.